# Cardinal arithmetic: $b\ge x>1$ and $b^2=b$ implies $x^b=2^b$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $x$ and $b$ represent cardinals. Assume that  $b\geq x > 1$ and $b^2=b$.
Prove that $x^b=2^b$. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $2^b=2^{b^2}=(2^b)^b\ge b^b$.

Comment: Cantor theorem.. Thanks

Comment: Actually, Cantor's theorem is $2^b > b$. We just need the much weaker $2^b\ge b$.

Comment: In this course we cannot rely on the fact that for all infinte cardinals b*b=b

Comment: Quite right too. That would be assuming the axiom of choice, which is not needed here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $b^2=b$ we know that $b$ is an infinite cardinal.  Then we have
$2^b \leq x^b \leq b^b$ since $2\leq x$ and $x\leq b$.  But $2^b=b^b$ for infinite cardinals.

It was pointed out that we should show the claimed $2^b=b^b$ in the above proof.  So let's give a proof of that.  First, we note that as $b\geq2$ then we have $2^b\leq b^b$, so we just need to show $b^b\leq 2^b$.  We know (left as exercise) that $2^b=|P(b)|$ and $b^b=|\{f:b\to b\}|$.  So it will suffice to construct an injection from $\{f:b\to b\}$ (the set of all functions from $b$ to $b$) into $P(b)$ (the powerset of $b$).  Now, we know that $b=|b\times b|$ (another exercise), so it is good enough to inject $\{f:b\to b\}$ into $P(b\times b)$.  But any function $f:b\to b$ corresponds to the set
$\{\langle\alpha,f(\alpha)\rangle\ :\ \alpha\in b\}\in P(b\times b)$. Note that distinct functions will map to distinct elements of $P(b\times b)$.  Thus
$b^b = |\{f:b\to b\}| \leq |P(b\times b)|=2^b$.

Comment: But just stating $2^b=b^b$ is close to simply stating the full result as a fact.

Comment: This is the first accepted answer I've seen with zero up-votes! @Nir: as you liked the answer enough to accept it, I assume you also intend to up-vote?

Comment: It's the only answer, so as bad as it is... :-)
(Maybe if I remove the dependence on AC I'll get a vote?)

Comment: sure, sorry guys :)